# How do you get edittext value and store it on textview while content of edittext is changed?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do you get edittext value and store it on textview while content of edittext is changed?

Answer (score 1):

```
NumofRevs_et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
    //XXX do something
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
  {
    title_text.setText(s);  // set the Text View Value using the edit text value
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

setTextWatcher on EditText ..... then  override onTextChange , beforeTextChange, afterTextChange as per your need